# Backbone.js Multiple Models within a View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Is it possible to create a view which lists a collection which is binded to different models? Also can the sort function be used?

For example I have 'sales' and 'accounts' model and would like to make a view with all the names of the people working in those departments.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. What you usually do is end up using a combination of applying event listeners on the collection, creating small subviews which represent each model and binding the model event handlers through that.

```
BigView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'ul',  // This view is a <ul> and we'll be adding the model views
    initialize: function() {
        // This collection represents the collection you passed in
        // For our purpose lets say it was a SalesCollection
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAllSales, this);
        this.collection.on('add', this.addSale, this);
    },
    addAllSales: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.collection.each(function(sale) {
            that.addSale(sale);
        });
    }
    addSale: function(model) {
        var view = new Subview({
            'model': model
        });
        this.$el.append(view.render().el);
    }
});

SaleView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('change', this.something, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html();  // Or whatever else you need to do to represent a sale as view
        return this;
    }
    something: function(model) {
        // Code for something
    }
});
```

So in this example, you basically have your main view that has a collection (e.g. sales). When the sales collection is reset, it fires up the `addAllSales()`. Each time an sale is added to the collection we add a subview that represents the specific model (sale model). In this subview, we take care of binding events to the model changes which then do something.

Comment: thanks. What I currently have is something similar to the code given, but then how can I add a record from the 'sales' model to the same view?

Comment: You mean how to add the salesModel represented by a salesView to the bigView that has the collection?

Comment: I have 2 models, Sales and Accounts which both have a field "name". I would like to have a list view with one column showing the name and the second showing the department. Sorry if the question was not that clear.

Comment: Oh, my answer might be overkill then. Basically if all you want to do is display the data in the list view in some format, you don't have to be creating subviews and stuff. I think it might be best if you just posted whatever code you have right now. That would frame this much more clearly. :-)

Comment: What I have till now is very similar to the code you posted. The only difference is that I have another view AccountsView which I want to add to the bigView.

Comment: Then you would just rinse and repeat what we did with the sales, except make sure you're adding each account view to presumably some other part of the DOM... right? :-) ?

Comment: thanks @orangewarp. What I did to be able to show multiple record views. In the initialize() method I added a paramater collections where I pass an object with all the collections required. And then render the views in a loop :). The problem that I had to implement a custom sorting method.

Comment: One good advice I got from Colin Moock was when you're learning, an answer that works is a correct answer. So I'm glad you got it to work. That said, I've been looking at your edits and there are some interesting things going on there. It's significantly different than my answer so the community consensus was to reject the edit. But I think it would make an interesting and informative side-by side, contrasting comparison. When I get the time, I might update my answer WITH your edited code and talk about some things I see, and things to streamline. :-)